# Entity Framework 6 Forces Distributed Transaction

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I need to run custom sql script during the Entity Framework migration. Script:

```
exec sp_executesql N'create view VIEW_TS_Shops as select * from openquery([TS-SQL], ''select * from Shops'')'
```

Migration fails with error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The operation could
>   not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "TS-SQL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction. OLE DB
>   provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "TS-SQL" returned message "The
>   partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions."

My attempts to solve the problem are listed below.

1. Use an argument "suppressTransaction:true" when calling *Sql()*
   method.
2. Disabling promotion of ditributed transaction in properties of linked server.

No result. 
How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

My solution with argument "suppressTransaction" is working, but I forgot to specify it for all SQL instructions that operate on the view.

Comment: *Don't* use a linked server. Connect to the appropriate server instead. It's your own code that requests a distributed transaction when it starts a query on one server and then tries to modify another server

Comment: That query is pretty bad too - it will read the *entire* `Shops` table from the linked server, bring it to the server you connect to and only then apply any filtering. You don't *need* `OPENQUERY` to query a linked server either. Just write `create view ABC as select * from [TS-SQL].ThatDatabase.dbo.Shops`

Comment: Perhaps an even better option is to create [a synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that points to the remote table `CREATE SYNONYM ThoseShops FOR [TS-SQL].ThatDatabase.dbo.Shops`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why does my query for creating view work without errors in SSMS?